# javascript window.location.href keeps adding to url

Tags: javascript, html, location-href

I have a simple dropdown that forwards to a new url onChange.

It looks like this:

```
function changeCompanyType(companyType) {
      window.location.href = 'type/'+companyType+'/';

    }
```

The first change works great and goes to the url:

> http://127.0.0.1/companies/type/bank/

The next time I click on the dropdown from the new page it adds type and the company type again:

> http://127.0.0.1/companies/type/bank/type/hosptial/

How can I just have the company type changed so the url doesn't keep being added to?

Comment: Your url needs to start with /

Comment: Add a slash in the beginning of `'/type/'+companyType+'/'` or else it will be using the relative url, which adds to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix with a forward slash (`/`)

```
window.location.href = '/type/'+companyType+'/';
                        ^ -- a slash to make an absolute url

// or (depends on what you want to do)
window.location.href = '/companies/type/'+companyType+'/';
                        ^ -- a slash to make an absolute url
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `'/'` at the front of the link like this

```
function changeCompanyType(companyType) {
  window.location.href = '/type/'+companyType+'/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function changeCompanyType(companyType) {
    window.location.href = '/type/'+companyType+'/';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line:

```
companyType = '';
```

after you have set the href.

Comment: Why? After you set `window.location.href` the page redirects

Comment: If it is a global variable it doesn't get deleted. We don't know if it is, because we can't see other part of the code.